# Sencha Touch Nestedlist JSON format Example

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm new to sencha. Using Sencha touch. I would like to make nested listing like first of list comes, when click on one of the link it goes to another listing, when click on second list's any link it opens image like that.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/nestedlist/

Above example is perfectly suitable for this one more than that below application.
http://touchstyle.mobi/app/

When i'm doing any modification in
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/nestedlist/
it gives no error or warning i'm using Fedora 11 linux Google Chrome.
Can anybody tell me what is the JSON perfect format for this nested listing. I will do it for dynamic.
So if anyone help to get static nested list it would be better.

Answer (score 3):

if you open the web inspector in safari you'll see for the example above, the data should be formatted like:

{"text":".","children":[{"fileName":"widgets","id":".\/widgets","cls":"folder"},{"fileName":"gestures","id":".\/gestures","cls":"folder"},{"fileName":"data","id":".\/data","cls":"folder"},{"fileName":"core","id":".\/core","cls":"folder"},{"fileName":"util","id":".\/util","cls":"folder"},{"fileName":"layout","id":".\/layout","cls":"folder"},{"fileName":"platform","id":".\/platform","cls":"folder"}]}

web inspector or firebug are mandatory for sencha hacking :)

brad